# Azure CDN custom domain for .lk not working

Tags: azure, cdn

We have hosted our static website under storage account and we want to point that to our custom domain(not .com we have a .lk domain(srilanka)). As per microsoft documentation we have added a CNAME record under our domain. Even we have added the cdnverify also. But that domain is not recognized under the azure cdn custom domain. We have waited more than a day. But we have tested with one .com domain that works fine. Any extra configurations we need to do for .lk domains?

Comment: is your blob container public?

Comment: @Sajeetharan its a private one. Do we need to change to public?

Comment: yes it needs to be public

Comment: @Sajeetharan I have changed that to public but no difference. If container accessibility is the issue then it should not work with .com also. Also i dont think CNAME records checking the container endpoints. Its checking the CDN endpoints that something like *.azureedge.net . correct me if i am wrong. thanks.

Comment: it might take sometime to get reflected

Comment: ok . I will wait sometime and let you know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214091/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-niroj).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment

- Make sure your blob container is [`public`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-custom-domain-name?tabs=azure-portal) .

> To confirm that your custom domain is mapped to your blob service
>   endpoint, create a blob in a public container within your storage
>   account.

- Validate the [`CDN endpoint`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cdn-how-to-use-cdn/) is properly configured

Comment: I dont thin there is an issue with public or private blobs. Also CDN endpoint configured properly and custom domain mapping working fine with one .com domain. Only issue I am facing is with .lk domain. Same way CNAME records added to the zone editor but still no luck for .lk domains